# Android - how to close notification in service started by startForeground?

Tags: java, android

Say I start a notification via the following in a service of my app:

```
notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.app_name), System.currentTimeMillis());
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, mainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
      initService.notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.app_name), "ibike rider", pendingIntent);

      startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

How would I go about `shutting down/cancelling` this service? And would it be possible to do this in another activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "started" service (no matter if it is a background or foreground service) can be started by `startService` call and stopped by `stopService` call.

- [Services | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)
- [LocalService demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LocalService.html)

If your service can handle multiple requests in its `onStartCommand` implementation then you can manage its lifecycle by additional calls of `startService`:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  // ...

  if (intent.getAction().equals(STOP_MY_SERVICE)) {
    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
  }

  if (intent.getAction().equals(START_FOREGROUND)) {

    // startForeground(...);

    return START_STICKY;
  }

  if (intent.getAction().equals(STOP_FOREGROUND)) {
    stopForeground(true);
    return START_STICKY;
  }

  // ...
  return START_STICKY;
}
```

For an example see [LocationService.java - GTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/LocationService.java)